How to remove Extra Attributes Error in Nextjs andclerk
I have been getting this warning in Next.js Application with clerk
I removed all extensions in the chrome but still this warning is not going away. And no this is warning is not in the hosted application.
I am wondering how to make it go away.


Warning: Extra attributes from the server: class,style
    at html
    at SWRConfig (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/swr/_internal/dist/index.mjs:565:13)
    at OrganizationProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@clerk/shared/dist/react/index.mjs:79:3)
    at ClerkContextProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@clerk/clerk-react/dist/index.mjs:1385:11)
    at ClerkProviderBase (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@clerk/clerk-react/dist/index.mjs:1439:11)
    at Hoc (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@clerk/clerk-react/dist/index.mjs:108:5)
    at ClerkNextOptionsProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@clerk/nextjs/dist/esm/client-boundary/NextOptionsContext.js:16:11)
    at ClientClerkProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@clerk/nextjs/dist/esm/app-router/client/ClerkProvider.js:25:13)
    at ClerkProvider (Server)
    at RootLayout (Server)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:74:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:82:11)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:76:9)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:84:11)
    at DevRootNotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/dev-root-not-found-boundary.js:33:11)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/app/ReactDevOverlay.js:87:9)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/app/hot-reloader-client.js:321:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:207:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:113:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:160:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:577:13)
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:112:27)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:117:11)




If you are using next.js 14 and using shadcn/ui, using shadcn's theme provider, try passing something like this:
<html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
       <body
         className={dm_sans.variable + " " + rethink_sans.variable}
         suppressHydrationWarning={true}
       >
         <ThemeProvider
           attributes="class"
           defaultTheme="system"
           enableSystem
           disableTransitionOnChange
         >
           {children}
         </ThemeProvider>
       </body>
     </html>

passing suppressHydrationWarning twice, both in the body and in the html, this solved the problem.

I was using NextJS 14 with shadcn, I added this: suppressHydrationWarning={true}, in the html and it solved my issue:


<html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning={true}>

<body>
  <QueryClientProvider>
    <ThemeProvider>{children}</ThemeProvider>
  </QueryClientProvider>
</body>

</html>



